# Executing tests using Unittest, runs only the last method(test) in the class in python

Tags: python, selenium, unit-testing, python-unittest

This is my code where I defined multiple methods (tests) and I want to run them by calling every test and defining some parameters using unittest.TestSuite()

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
import datetime
import time
import unittest
from collections import defaultdict


class LoginDex(unittest.TestCase):

    def __init__(self, metname, searchType=None, searchValue=None, configType=None, abNouType=None, scenarioNameDC=None,
                 retentieType=None, offerChoice=None, scenarioName_PC=None,
                 isNumarNou=None, scenarioName_GDPR=None, tipFactura=None, scenariuKey=None, scenarioName_NrNou=None):
        super(LoginDex, self).__init__(metname)
        self.searchType = searchType
        self.searchValue = searchValue
        self.configType = configType
        self.abNouType = abNouType
        self.scenarioNameDC = scenarioNameDC
        self.retentieType = retentieType
        self.offerChoice = offerChoice
        self.scenarioName_PC = scenarioName_PC
        self.isNumarNou = isNumarNou
        self.scenarioName_GDPR = scenarioName_GDPR
        self.scenarioName_NrNou = scenarioName_NrNou
        self.tipFactura = tipFactura
        self.scenariiDict = defaultdict(dict)
        self.scenarioNumber = 0
        self.stepNumber = 0
        self.scenariuKey = scenariuKey

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(self):  # self.cap = DesiredCapabilities().INTERNETEXPLORER
        # self.cap['ignoreProtectedModeSettings'] = True
        # self.cap['IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings'] = True
        # self.cap['nativeEvents'] = True
        # self.cap['ignoreZoomSetting'] = True
        # self.cap['requireWindowFocus'] = False
        # self.cap['INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS'] = True
        # self.browser = webdriver.Ie(capabilities=self.cap,
        # executable_path=r'C:\Users\FagetL\Downloads\IEDriverServer_Win32_3.150.1\IEDriverServer.exe')
        # self.browser.get("https://dexuat2.aws.connex.ro/retail/login")
        # self.browser.implicitly_wait(15)
        # time.sleep(3)(self):

        ###CHROME DRIVER
        caps = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
        caps['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True
        self.browser = webdriver.Ie(capabilities=caps, executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
        self.browser.get("http://localhost:123")
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(15)

    def test_Login(self):
        # Click ok
        LoginDex.logScenariu(self, 'Click pe butonul Ok')
        search_form = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div[3]/div/button')
        search_form.click()

        # Find username and insert user
        LoginDex.logScenariu(self, 'Find and insert Nume Utilizator')
        search_form_user = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="username"]')
        search_form_user.send_keys('mihaela.filip1')

        # Find password and insert pass
        LoginDex.logScenariu(self, 'Find and insert Password')
        search_form_pass = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="password"]')
        search_form_pass.send_keys('abc')

        search_form_logg = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-automation-id='login-button']")
        search_form_logg.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        # Search dealer(1) on page and click continue
        time.sleep(3)
        select = Select(
            self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@data-automation-id='select-dealer']")).select_by_index(1)

        # select_option_one = select.select_by_index(1)
        search_from_dealer = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-automation-id='dealer-login-button']")
        search_from_dealer.click()
        # time.sleep(30)

    def test_search(self):
        # Laur
        # Input msisdn harcoded
        LoginDex.logScenariu(self, self.scenariuKey, 'Search by MSISDN')
        if self.searchType == 'MSISDN':
            # msisdn = '722848655'
            time.sleep(3)
            select_msisdn = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]')
            select_msisdn.click()
            input_msisdn = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="search"]')
            input_msisdn.send_keys(self.searchValue)
            self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-automation-id='search-button']").click()


        elif self.searchType == 'CNP':
            time.sleep(3)
            select_cnp = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]')
            select_cnp.click()
            input_cnp = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="search"]')
            input_cnp.send_keys(self.searchValue)
        else:
            print('No input')

    def test_dashboard_CustDetails(self):
        pass

    def test_dashboard_Config(self):

        # Gabi
        if self.configType == 'ACHIZITIE':
            LoginDex.wait_loadingCircle(self)
            LoginDex.logScenariu(self, 'Click Abonament Nou')
            LoginDex.click_js(self, "//div[@data-automation-id='new-subscriber-link']")
            if self.abNouType == 'GA':

                LoginDex.logScenariu(self, 'Click Numar Nou')
                LoginDex.click_js(self, "//li[contains(@class,'tab bold active')]")

                if self.scenarioNameDC == 'CR true':

                    LoginDex.logScenariu(self, 'click Credit Rate = "Da"')
                    LoginDex.click_js(self, """//input[@name="isCustomerConsent" and @value='true']""").click()

                    LoginDex.logScenariu(self, 'Type Numar Contact')
                    LoginDex.type_js(self, xpath='input[name="contactNumber"]', value='730963536')

                    LoginDex.logScenariu(self, 'Click Continua')
                    LoginDex.click_js(self, """//button[contains(@class,'primary bold right-align')]""")

                elif self.scenarioNameDC == 'CR false':


                    LoginDex.logScenariu(self, 'click Credit Rate = "Nu"')
                    LoginDex.click_js(self, """//input[@name="isCustomerConsent" and @value='false']""").click()

                    LoginDex.logScenariu(self, 'Type Numar Contact')
                    LoginDex.type_js(self, xpath='input[name="contactNumber"]', value='730963536')

                    # CLick Continua
                    LoginDex.click_js(self, """//button[contains(@class,'primary bold right-align')]""")

            elif self.abNouType == 'MNP':
                pass
            elif self.abNouType == 'MFP':
                pass
        elif self.configType == 'RETENTIE':
            pass

    def test_page_Configureaza(self):
        # Razvan
        if self.offerChoice == 'PachetPromo':
            if self.scenarioName_PC == 'Scenariu_PC_Stock_1':
                # Click first offer
                select_first_offer = LoginDex.click_js(self,
                                                       "//div[contains(@class,'cards-section space-unset')]//div[1]//div[3]//div[1]//button[1]")
                # Click continue
                select_continute = LoginDex.click_js(self, "//button[contains(@class,'footer-btn-primary')]")
            else:
                print('Scenariu1_PC_Stock_1 - NO')
        elif self.offerChoice == 'ConfigOferte':
            if self.scenarioName_PC == 'Scenariul_Config_Service_DS':
                select_cfg = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='accordion-links']//div[1]")
                select_cfg.click()
        elif self.offerChoice == 'Vezimaimult':
            if self.scenarioName_PC == 'Scenariul3_See_More':
                select_see = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'accordion-links')]//div[2]")
                select_see.click()
        # offerChoice -> ('PachetPromo', 'ConfigOferte', 'Vezimaimult')
        # scenarioName_PC -> (code_to_xls)

    def test_page_Detail_ValidateCustDetails(self):
        pass

    def test_page_Detail_UtilizatorPlusNrNou(self):
        # IsNumarNou = True / false
        # True = verifica daca este numar display si indiferent click pe alege numar .... numar special working....
        # if globalScenario == 'MNP_SD':
        #     if scenariu == 1:
        if self.abNouType == 'GA':
            print('GA')
            if self.isNumarNou == 'True':
                if self.scenarioName_NrNou == 'Select Numar Special':
                    # element = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/span')
                    # if element.text == '- - - - - - - - - -':
                    alege_no_click = LoginDex.click_js(self,
                                                       '//*[@id="root"]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/h6')
                    alege_no_elm = LoginDex.click_js(self,
                                                     '//*[@id="root"]/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span')
                    if 'Nu sunt' in alege_no_elm.text:
                        alege_no_spl = LoginDex.click_js(self, '//*[@id="root"]/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]')
                        input_no_spl = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="firstDigits"]')
                        dig = 22
                        input_no_spl.send_keys(dig)
                        cauta_no_spl = LoginDex.click_js(self,
                                                         "//div[@data-automation-id='special-number-form-find-button']")
                        # LoginDex.wait_loadingCircle(self)
                        try:
                            element_no_spl = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(
                                "//div[@class='no-numbers-error-text']/span")
                            print(element_no_spl.text)
                            while self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Nu au fost')]"):
                                print('Start')
                                input_no_spl_c = LoginDex.click_js(self,
                                                                   "//div[@data-automation-id='special-number-form-clear-button']")
                                dig += 1
                                print(dig)
                                input_no_spl.send_keys(dig)
                                cauta_no_spl = LoginDex.click_js(self,
                                                                 "//div[@data-automation-id='special-number-form-find-button']")
                                time.sleep(2)
                            click_on_conti = LoginDex.click_js(self,
                                                               "//button[@data-automation-id='number-allocation-popup-continue-button']")
                        except NoSuchElementException:
                            print('exceptie ....')
                    else:
                        lege_no_spl = LoginDex.click_js(self, '//*[@id="root"]/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]')
                        input_no_spl = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="firstDigits"]')
                        dig = 22
                        input_no_spl.send_keys(dig)
                        cauta_no_spl = LoginDex.click_js(self,
                                                         "//div[@data-automation-id='special-number-form-find-button']")
                        # LoginDex.wait_loadingCircle(self)
                        try:
                            element_no_spl = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(
                                "//div[@class='no-numbers-error-text']/span")
                            print(element_no_spl.text)
                            while self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Nu au fost')]"):
                                print('Start')
                                input_no_spl_c = LoginDex.click_js(self,
                                                                   "//div[@data-automation-id='special-number-form"
                                                                   "-clear-button']")
                                dig += 1
                                print(dig)
                                input_no_spl.send_keys(dig)
                                cauta_no_spl = LoginDex.click_js(self,
                                                                 "//div[@data-automation-id='special-number-form-find"
                                                                 "-button']")
                                time.sleep(2)
                            click_on_conti = LoginDex.click_js(self,
                                                               "//button[@data-automation-id='number-allocation-popup"
                                                               "-continue-button']")
                        except NoSuchElementException:
                            print('exceptie ....')

                    click_on_conti = LoginDex.click_js(self,
                                                       "//button[@data-automation-id='number-allocation-popup"
                                                       "-continue-button']")
        elif self.abNouType == 'MNP':
            pass
        elif self.abNouType == 'MFP':
            pass

            input_sim = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='newSimNumber']")
            sim = '8940019999999591673'
            # To Do: white pentru sim, daca sim-ul este gresit retry
            input_sim.send_keys(sim)

    def test_page_Detail_GDPR(self):
        LoginDex.wait_loadingCircle(self)
        # if globalScenrio == 'MFP'
        #     if numarScenariu == '1'
        if self.scenarioName_GDPR == 'Scenariu_GDPR_allYES':
            # Check VDF 1 YES All
            LoginDex.check_button(self,
                                  "/html/body/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div["
                                  "2]/label/input[1]",
                                  '/html/body/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div['
                                  '2]/label/span',
                                  'value')
            # #Check Partner 1 YES All
            LoginDex.check_button(self,
                                  '/html/body/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div['
                                  '3]/label/input',
                                  '/html/body/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div['
                                  '3]/label/span',
                                  'value')
            # # # Check VDF 2 YES All
            LoginDex.check_button(self,
                                  '/html/body/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div['
                                  '2]/label/input',
                                  "//body/div[@id='root']/div[@id='root']/div/div["
                                  "@class='personal-details-exisit']/div[@class='wrap-content']/div["
                                  "@class='content-data']/div[@class='content-data content-data-100']/div["
                                  "@class='order-summary-general-data']/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/label[1]/span[1]",
                                  'value')
            # # # Check Partner 2 YES All
            LoginDex.check_button(self,
                                  '/html/body/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div['
                                  '3]/label/input',
                                  '/html/body/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div['
                                  '3]/label/span',
                                  'value')

            if self.scenarioName_GDPR == 'Scenariu_GDPR_allNo':
                pass

        # scenarioName_GDPR -> (code_to_xls)

    def test_page_Detail_ContNou(self):
        # tipFactura -> ('TIPARITA','ELECTRONICA')
        pass

    def test_sendToVOS(self):

        click_continue = LoginDex.click_js(self, "//button[@data-automation-id='summary-configuration-submit-btn']")
        type_email = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='email']")
        type_email.clear()
        email = 'laurentiu.faget1@vodafone.com'
        type_email.send_keys(email)
        type_phone = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='phone']")
        phone = '730044448'
        type_phone.send_keys(phone)
        send_vos = LoginDex.click_js(self, "//button[@data-automation-id='validate-contact-submit-button']")

    ####Utilitare####

    def wait_loadingCircle(self):
        try:
            while self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="sk-circle-container"]').is_displayed() is True:
                time.sleep(1)
        except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException, TimeoutException):
            print('Element loading a disparut')

    def get_text(self, xpath):
        try:
            WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
            return self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text
        except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException, TimeoutException) as e:
            print('exceptie {} pentru xPath : {}'.format(str(e), xpath))

    def type_js(self, xpath, value):
        try:
            WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
            self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementByXpath({}).value='{}'".format(xpath, value))
        except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException, TimeoutException) as e:
            print('exceptie {} pentru xPath : {}'.format(str(e), xpath))

    def click_js(self, xpath):
        try:
            WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)))
            self.browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath))
        except (NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException) as e:
            print('exceptie {} pentru xPath : {}'.format(str(e), xpath))

    def check_button(self, xpath, xpathCLick=None, value=None):
        if xpathCLick == None:
            xpathCLick = xpath
        if self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).get_attribute(value) == 'false':
            LoginDex.click_js(self, xpathCLick)

    def uncheck_button(self, xpath, xpathCLick=None, value=None):
        if xpathCLick == None:
            xpathCLick = xpath
        if self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).get_attribute(value) == 'true':
            LoginDex.click_js(self, xpathCLick)

    def logScenariu(self, stepValue, key=None):
        if key not in self.scenariiDict.keys():
            self.scenariiDict[key] = {}
        self.stepNumber += 1
        self.scenariiDict[key].update({'Pasul_{}'.format(self.stepNumber): stepValue})

    def getScenarii(self):
        print(self.scenariiDict)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(self):
        # pass
        self.browser.close()


testDefinitions = {
    'Test Case 1': {'searchType': 'MSISDN', 'searchValue': '722848655', 'configType': "ACHIZITIE", 'abNouType': 'GA',
                    'offerChoice': 'PachetPromo', 'scenarioName_PC': 'Scenariu_PC_Stock_1', 'isNumarNou': 'True',
                    'scenarioName_NrNou': 'Select Numar Special', 'scenarioName_GDPR': 'Scenariu_GDPR_allYES',
                    'scenarioNameDC': 'CR true'}}

if __name__ == '__main__':

    for i in testDefinitions.keys():
        suite = unittest.TestSuite()
        suite.addTest(LoginDex(metname='test_Login'))
        suite.addTest(LoginDex(metname='test_search', searchType=testDefinitions[i]['searchType'],
                               searchValue=testDefinitions[i]['searchValue']))
        suite.addTest(LoginDex(metname='test_dashboard_Config', configType=testDefinitions[i]['configType'],
                               abNouType=testDefinitions[i]['abNouType'],
                               scenarioNameDC=testDefinitions[i]['scenarioNameDC']))
        suite.addTest(LoginDex(metname='test_page_Configureaza', offerChoice=testDefinitions[i]['offerChoice'],
                               scenarioName_PC=testDefinitions[i]['scenarioName_PC'],
                               abNouType=testDefinitions[i]['abNouType']))
        suite.addTest(LoginDex(metname='test_page_Detail_UtilizatorPlusNrNou', isNumarNou=testDefinitions[i]['isNumarNou'],
                               scenarioName_NrNou=testDefinitions[i]['scenarioName_NrNou'],
                               abNouType=testDefinitions[i]['abNouType']))
        suite.addTest(LoginDex(metname='test_page_Detail_GDPR', scenarioName_GDPR=testDefinitions[i]['scenarioName_GDPR']))
        suite.addTest(LoginDex(metname='test_sendToVOS'))
        suite.addTest(LoginDex(metname='getScenarii'))
        suite.addTest(LoginDex(metname='tearDownClass'))
        unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

When I run it, it executes test_sendToVOS method instead of what I gave it in suite obj(suite = unittest.TestSuite())

If i remove if **name** == '**main**': it runs from the first test to the last, but it does it two times every time

How can i make it to run the tests as described in the suits that I'm defining with the method names and variables in that order?

Comment: How do you run it?

Comment: To clarify: if you run it as expected (`python logindex.py`), you should see no difference with or without `if __name__=='__main__`, so I suspect you are doing something else to run it.